# AWS VPC route traffic to Client VPN connections

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-vpc, openvpn

I have successfully configured an AWS Client VPN connection to a box running OpenVPN. I can access any devices on my VPC, which I've allowed access to.

Can I configure my VPC instances (an EC2 for example) to route traffic (SSH for example) to a client connected to the VPN?

Currently I cannot ssh to a client connected. I don't see any options to add a route to the Client VPN network. I've allowed all traffic in the Client VPN security group.

Is this a limitation of the Client VPN? If I want my VPN clients to be accessible from the VPC, will I need to configure a site to site connection?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, Install Openswan and you can configure site to site vpn between any of the Ec2 to your Server for other instance to route through openswan, you need to change routing and point to openswan ec2. (You can also use AWS VPN as well to save all these routing).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll go that route.

Answer (score 0):

Per the recommendation of [@James Dean](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11097368/james-dean), I configured a site to site between the devices which needed two way communication.

Comment: Were you able to do so without a static IP and access to the client-side VPN?